# confusion regarding wild card parametrized types

Tags: java, generics

I had 2 classes as below. From my understanding compiler must not complain at line 4 (class WildCard) as my parametrized type is (Node? super Number> s0), as object is super to number in parametrized type. but compiler is complaining at 4,8 and 9. why so.

```
public class Node<E> {

    private E data;

    public void setData(E obj) {
        data = obj;
    }

    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }
}


public class WildCard {


    static void checkIt(Node<? super Number> s0)
    {
        Object object=new Object(); //1
        Number number =1.5; //2
        Integer integer=10; //3

        s0.setData(object); //4
        s0.setData(number); //5
        s0.setData(integer); //6

        object=s0.getData(); //7
        number=s0.getData(); //8
        integer=s0.getData(); //9
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is as follows:

`Node<? super Number>` means you could pass in any `Node` with a parameter that is of type `Number` or a super type, e.g. `Object`.

Since you don't know the exact type of that generic parameter some operations are not allowed.

Here's a short breakdown of why some lines compile and some don't:

- `s0.setData(object);` doesn't compile because you could have a `Node<Number>` which would not all you to add an arbitrary object
- `s0.setData(number);` compiles since `Number` matches all possible types for the parameter
- `s0.setData(integer);` compiles because `Integer` extends `Number` and thus the line above applies
- `object=s0.getData();` compiles because any data object extends `Object`, always
- `number=s0.getData();` doesn't compile because you could have a `Node<Object>` and thus the data object might have a different type (e.g. `String`)
- `integer=s0.getData();`  doesn't compile, same reason as the line above

Answer (score 0):

The *Java Language Specification* says:

> Wildcards may be given explicit bounds, just like regular type
>   variable declarations. An upper bound is signified by the following
>   syntax, where `B` is the bound:
>
> `? extends B`
>
> Unlike ordinary type variables declared in a method signature, no type
>   inference is required when using a wildcard. Consequently, it is
>   permissible to declare lower bounds on a wildcard, using the following
>   syntax, where `B` is a lower bound:
>
> `? super B`

```
Reference(T referent, ReferenceQueue<? super T> queue);
```

Here, the referent can be inserted into any queue whose element type is a **supertype** of the
type `T` of the referent; `T` is the lower bound for the wildcard.